# How to strip out string after question mark?

Tags: javascript

I have a bunch of urls with similar format so here are example urls:

```
http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg?818629
http://safebooru.org//samples/567/sample_15b9d81bb58b540a6515c1d61cf54f6b7e38d5ab.jpg?569623
```

What I want to do is strip out the text after the ? and including the ? so the output should like this:

```
http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg
http://safebooru.org//samples/567/sample_15b9d81bb58b540a6515c1d61cf54f6b7e38d5ab.jpg
```

How can you do this with javascript?

Comment: [What have  you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @EdibleMuffin why u want that through javascript?There are other easier ways than javascript

Comment: @Maizere it might be because of the platform if his larger project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

```
var str="How are you doing today?";
var n=str.split(" ");
```

Result :

How,are,you,doing,today?

In your case :

```
var url = 'http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg?818629';
var array = url.split("?");
var myNewUrl = array[0];
```

Comment: No need for the junk variable. `var myNewUrl = url.split("?")[0]` is sufficient. Also, http://w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

URL: `http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg?818629`

Regex: `.*\?`

Matches: `http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg`

Test [here](http://regexpal.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg?818629';

var modified = string.replace(/\?.*$/, '');

console.log(modified)

// displays
// http://safebooru.org//images/813/a8b349b60d0c448eb86cfb99e24318ad6d48b7df.jpg
```